# how to show aggregation results on Rails 4

Tags: ruby, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4, aggregation, moped

Syntax in mongodb:

```
db.orders.aggregate(
   {$unwind: "$lines"},
   {$group : 
             {_id: {sku: "$lines.sku", desc: "$lines.description"}, 
             qty : {$sum : 1}}},{ $sort : { qty : -1}}
                   )
```

I want to to show the result of the above query on Rails.

I'm using Mongoid with Rails 4 and my Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
```

As I understand, the only way to write the query above is to install gem for **moped** driver. 
So, my **1st question** is how that line should be declared in the Gemfile for Rails 4 and Ruby 2.0 ?

I assume the query in moped would look like:

```
Order.collection.aggregate(
    {"$unwind" => "$lines"},
    {"$group" => {"_id" => {"sku" => "$lines.sku", desc => "$lines.description"}, 
    qty => {"$sum" => 1}}},
    { "$sort" => { "qty" => -1}})
```

I would like to show results of this query, by clicking a button on the index page without passing parameters. 
The **2nd question** is that I can't figure out how to change controller and index view page to put a button that will call this query.

---

UPDATE

index method part of the controller as below:

```
  def index
    @orders = if params[:search]
      Order.search(params[:search]).queryable.asc(:_id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    elsif params[:search_from] && params[:search_to]
      Order.search_date(params[:search_from], params[:search_to]).queryable.asc(:_id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    else
      Order.shipping_today(Date.today, Date.today).queryable.asc(:_id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Date: <%= Date.today %></h1>

<%= form_tag orders_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p>Order date range:<br>  
    <%= text_field_tag :search_from, params[:search_from] %> - <%= text_field_tag :search_to, params[:search_to] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag orders_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    <%= link_to "Reset", orders_path %>
</p>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag orders_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p>
    <%= submit_tag "Statistics", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>

<div class="digg_pagination">
    <div class="page_info">
      <%= page_entries_info @orders %>
    </div>
    <%= will_paginate @orders, :container => false %>
  </div>

  <br />

<table border = 1 >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Shipping date</th>
      <th>Order #</th>
      <th>Ship to name</th>
      <th>Tracking #</th>
      <th>Shipped</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= order.shipping_date %></td>
      <td><%= link_to order.order_number, order_path(order) %></td>
      <td><%= order.ship_to_fname %></td>
      <td><%= order.track_num %></td>
      <td><%= order.ship_date %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(order) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'New', new_order_path(order) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', order, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Order', new_order_path %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The line in Gemfile that you wrote `gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'` should be enough for that query to work.

After `aggregate` commant you'll get an array with the result of the aggregation.
You can assign it to the instance variable in the controller and iterate on it in view.

For example:

```
# LinesController
def index
  @lines = Order.collection.aggregate(
    {"$unwind" => "$lines"},
    {"$group" => {"_id" => {"sku" => "$lines.sku", desc => "$lines.description"}, 
    qty => {"$sum" => 1}}},
    { "$sort" => { "qty" => -1}})
end

# lines/index.html.erb
<ul>
  <% @lines.each do |line| %>
    <li>
      <b><%= line['_id']['sku'] %></b>
      <%= line['qty'] %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my post with index method that I already have. My question was not clear, so I've updated my 2nd question as well. I understand what you showed above, I just wonder how I will call this query by clicking a button on the index view page and where in the index method should I put the code you showed above.